# MySQL transaction rollback not working in TypeScript

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript

I try to create an API to receive user data to create a new job post.

```
const sqlQuery : QueryFunction = (queryString : string, params : any[] | null) => {
        return new Promise<QueryResult>((resolve, reject) => {
            pool.getConnection(function(err, con){
                if(err){
                    con.release();
                    reject(err);
                }

                con.query(queryString , params, (err, results) => {
                    if(err){
                        con.release();
                        reject(err);
                    }
                    else{
                        con.release();
                        resolve(results);
                    }   
                });       
            });
        });
};

function runTransaction(queryFunction: TransactionFunction): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.getConnection(async function (err, con){
            if (err) {
                con.release();
                reject(err);
            }

            con.beginTransaction(async function (err){
                if (err) {
                    con.release();
                    reject(err);
                }

                try {
                    await queryFunction();
                    con.commit(function(err) {
                        if (err){
                            con.rollback(function(err){
                                if(err){
                                    con.release();
                                    reject(err);
                                }
                                con.release();
                                reject(err);
                            });
                        } else {
                            con.release();
                            resolve(); 
                        }
                    });
                } catch (error) {
                    con.rollback(function(err){
                        if(err){
                            con.release();
                            reject(err);
                        }
                        con.release();
                        reject(error);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
}

//Api Function
app.post('/jobs/', async function (req : RequestParams, res, next) {
    const userAuthenticationToken : string =  req.get('Authorization') as string;

    const authenticationStatus : number = await checkAuthentication(userAuthenticationToken);

    if(authenticationStatus === 3){
        errorMessage = JSON.stringify('Unauthorized request, please make sure you include authorization token');
        res.status(500);
        res.send(errorMessage);
        next();
        return;
    }
    else if(authenticationStatus === 2){
        errorMessage = JSON.stringify('Unauthorized request, please make sure you include correct authorization token');
        res.status(500);
        res.send(errorMessage);
        next();
        return;
    }
    else if(authenticationStatus === 1){
        let jobPostTile : string = req.body.jobTitle;
        const jobPostContent : string = req.body.jobContent;
        const jobCategoryID : string = req.body.categoryID;
        const jobPermitTypeID : string = req.body.permitTypeID;
        let jobLocations : string[] = req.body.locations;

        if(!jobPostTile){
            errorMessage = JSON.stringify('Parameter jobTitle is required.');
            res.status(400);
            res.send(errorMessage);
            next();
            return;
        }
        else if(!jobPostContent){
            errorMessage = JSON.stringify('Parameter jobContent is required.');
            res.status(400);
            res.send(errorMessage);
            next();
            return;
        }
        else if(!jobLocations){
            errorMessage = JSON.stringify('Please include at least one location id for this job');
            res.status(400);
            res.send(errorMessage);
            next();
            return;
        }
        else if(isStringArray(jobLocations) === false){
            errorMessage = JSON.stringify('Parameter "locations" need to be in array format');
            res.status(400);
            res.send(errorMessage);
            next();
            return;
        }

        if(jobPostTile && jobPostContent && jobLocations){
            jobPostTile = jobPostTile.replace("%20","");
            try{
                await runTransaction(async query => {
                    let insertResult = await sqlQuery(`
                    INSERT INTO job_posts 
                    (post_title,post_content,category_id,permit_type_id) 
                    VALUES (?,?,?,?)`,[jobPostTile, jobPostContent, jobCategoryID, jobPermitTypeID]); //Insert new job post to `job_posts` table

                    const numID : number = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(insertResult)).insertId;

                    throw new Error();

                    jobLocations.forEach(async function(item, index){
                        let currentLocationID = jobLocations[index];
                        await sqlQuery(`
                        INSERT INTO job_posts_locations
                        (job_post_id, location_id)
                        VALUES (?,?)`,[numID, currentLocationID]); //Insert new data to `job_posts_locations` table
                    });
                });
                res.send(JSON.stringify("Insert successfully"));
                next();
            }catch(error){
                errorMessage = JSON.stringify("Error, please try again");
                res.status(500);
                res.send(errorMessage);
                next();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        errorMessage = JSON.stringify("Unknown authentication error, please check your authentication credentials and try to submit again");
        res.status(500);
        res.send(errorMessage);
        next();
        return;
    }
});
```

I am debugging the script I created by adding `throw new Error()` in different lines to test if the transaction function working. But the rollback isn't working, the data in INSERT query still stored in database.

Comment: which orm are you using?

Comment: @MarcoMerola Hi, I am not using any ORM, i only use plain SQL query